# Is there a theorem about eigenvalues of sum of matrices?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let's suppose I know $\lambda_i$ to be an eigenvalue of the real negative definite square matrix $A$ of size $n$. $\lambda_i$ can either be real or complex (and $\lambda_{i+1}$ will then be its conjugate).

Is there a theorem or proof that could answer the question

> For which $B$ is $\lambda_i$ an eigenvalue of $A+B$?

i.e.

> Can a real matrix $B$ be found such that $det(A+B-\lambda_i I_n)=0 \;\;\; \forall i \in [1,n]$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your $n \times n$ matrix $A$ has $n$ distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_i$, 
what you're asking is that $A + B$ has the same characteristic polynomial as $A$.
One possibility is $B = f(A) - A$ where $f$ is a polynomial that permutes the 
eigenvalues, i.e. $f(\lambda_i) = \lambda_{\sigma(i)}$, where $\sigma$ is a permutation of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$.  Such an $f$ can be found by Lagrange interpolation.

By the way, if you're talking about a **symmetric** negative definite matrix (conventions differ on whether this is part of the definition), the eigenvalues are all real.

Comment: thank you. No, $A$ is not symmetric and full rank. I had assumed that $B$ could only have spanned the null space of $A$ since $Ax = \lambda_i x$ and $(A+B)x = \lambda_i x$ then $Bx = 0$
or is your answer still saying the same, only in different words?

Comment: No.  In my construction, the eigenvector of $A+B$ for $\lambda_i$ is an eigenvector of $A$, but for a different eigenvalue.  For example, for $A = \pmatrix{1 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 2 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & 3\cr}$ you could take $B = \pmatrix{1 & 0 & 0\cr 0 & 1 & 0\cr 0 & 0 & -2\cr}$.

Comment: thanks. I will go through your answer a bit longer and then I will accept it and eventually ask separately any follow up I might have.